# Can I user fasterxml to write a date as ISODate to use an expiring mongodb index?

Tags: java, mongodb, serialization, mapping, fasterxml

I am using [FasterXML](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/) to map my objects to MongoDB

I'd like to use an [expiring index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/expire-data/#expire-data-from-collections-by-setting-ttl), but for that, I need an ISODate field on my document.

If my java class has a Date field, it gets serialised either by a number or a string, using the `DateSerializer` as described here: http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFAQDateHandling

I tracked it down to this function:

```
/**
 * Method that will handle serialization of Date(-like) values, using
 * {@link SerializationConfig} settings to determine expected serialization
 * behavior.
 * Note: date here means "full" date, that is, date AND time, as per
 * Java convention (and not date-only values like in SQL)
 */
public final void defaultSerializeDateValue(Date date, JsonGenerator jgen)
    throws IOException, JsonProcessingException
{
    // [JACKSON-87]: Support both numeric timestamps and textual
    if (isEnabled(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)) {
        jgen.writeNumber(date.getTime());
    } else {
        jgen.writeString(_dateFormat().format(date));
    }
}
```

None of those two paths ends up writing a standard mongodb date type, and thus my index does not work.

Is there a way to force the java `Date` type to be serialised as it would be when creating the document from the mongo shell?  Alternatively, can I automatically add the field via a "trigger" or something like that? (with the objective of bypassing the serializer altogether)

Comment: I'm just curious to know: are you using [MongoJack](http://mongojack.org/)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have exactly the same problem with new version of FasterXML. (2.7.3). FasterXML now have a "Codec" to handle objects, beside of serializers. 
I resolved that issue with a serializer that invalidate the codec so the date object arrive to mongo driver without been touch.

```
private static class MongoDateSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Date> {

    public void serialize(Date value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        TokenBuffer buffer = (TokenBuffer) jgen;
        ObjectCodec codec = buffer.getCodec();
        buffer.setCodec(null);

        buffer.writeObject(value);

        buffer.setCodec(codec);
    }
}
```

Look the line `buffer.writeObject(value)` , thats the way that old versions of FasterXML just did it.

Comment: I am also facing same issue... I tried this solution but I am getting ClassCast Exception. 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.WriterBasedJsonGenerator cannot be cast to com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.TokenBuffer


@juan Francisco.. Can you please tell me what is the issue ?

Answer (score -1):

you can initialize the ObjectMapper with your own DateFormat, by invoke setDateFormat().

for example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException,
        IOException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = null;
    mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy~MM~dd");
    mapper.setDateFormat(sdf); // 1.8 and above
    //mapper.getSerializationConfig().setDateFormat(sdf); // for earlier versions (deprecated for 1.8+)
    Map<String, Date> data = new HashMap<>();
    data.put("Key", new Date());
    System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(data));
}
```

note: SimpleDateFormat is not thread safe.

or you can annotated bean with JsonSerialize.

for example:

```
public static class User {

    private int id;

    private Date createTime;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @JsonSerialize(using = DateJsonSerializer.class)
    public Date getCreateTime() {
        return createTime;
    }

    public void setCreateTime(Date createTime) {
        this.createTime = createTime;
    }
}
```

and here is DateJsonSerializer.

```
public class DateJsonSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Date> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(Date date, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        jgen.writeString("generate ISODate yourself");
    }
}
```